# How to refer to constructor methods when calling a function as an object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, prototype, this

More questions about prototype inheritance, fun fun. I am making a Slack bot and am trying to keep my code neat and tidy. I have made a constructor for the bot to handle all needed methods and properties.

I was going to make an object on the prototype that held a bunch of functions related to a specific functional area (responding to chat commands). The problem is, I still need to refer to functions on the prototype from within these methods...I dunno how to do that:

```
// generic function I put on prototype
SmashBot.prototype.postMessage = function() {
    'do stuff'
}

// helper object full of functions I need
SmashBot.prototype.commands = {

  tournament: function(message) {
    this.postMessage('stuff');     // Method on SmashBot Prototype i need to use
    console.log(this)     // refers to this object (Smashbot.commands)
  },

  self: (message) => {
    this.createTourney('stuff')   // another method on prototype
    console.log(this);   // lexical arrow function makes 'this' just refer to '{}', not the constructor
  }
}
```

and then from another function on the prototype:

```
this.commands.tournament()   
      // <--- this.postMessage() is not a function
```

So my question is....is there any neat way to put a bunch of functions in an object in order to use them, or do they all have to be directly on the prototype themselves? I tried putting them in the constructor, but same thing happened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.commands.tournament.apply(this)` should work

Comment: @Maximus that works! However, would there be any way to pass a parameter on to the function? EDIT Nevermind, I found it. Just pass it after the this value Thanks!

Comment: You can pass arguments with `call`: `this.commands.tournament.call(this, 'message')`

Comment: that works as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do in this way

```
SmashBot.prototype.commands = function(){
let self = this;
return {
    tournament: function (message) {
        self.postMessage('stuff');     // Method on SmashBot Prototype i need to use
        console.log(this)     // refers to this object (Smashbot.commands)
    },
    self: (message) => {
        self.createTourney('stuff')   // another method on prototype
        console.log(this);   // lexical arrow function makes 'this' just refer to '{}', not the constructor
    }
}
```

};

And call it

```
this.commands().tournament('message')
```

Comment: Oh that's a great idea too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `commands` level by using `Object.assign`:

```
// helper object full of functions I need
Object.assign(SmashBot.prototype, {

  tournament: function(message) {
    this.postMessage('stuff');     // Method on SmashBot Prototype i need to use
    console.log(this)     // refers to this object (Smashbot.commands)
  },

  self: (message) => {
    this.createTourney('stuff')   // another method on prototype
    console.log(this);   // lexical arrow function makes 'this' just refer to '{}', not the constructor
  }
}
```

So, now you can write:

```
var obj = new Smashbot();
obj.tournament('test');
```